# Light sensor on different devices

Tags: android, device, sensors

I tried to create a small application that calculates the light through the light sensor, but different devices give me completely different values. I used the max value to calculate a percentage, but my xperia and my samsung are in the same place (near the wall outside my house, under the roof) and the first device gives me 90% (90k/102k) and the second one gives me 12% (8k/64k). Is there a way to avoid this problem?

```
    public final void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) 
    {
        if( event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT)
        {
            currentLux=(int) event.values[0];
            float perc=(currentLux*100)/max;
            lightTextBox.setText(lightTextBox.getText()+String.valueOf(perc)+" * ");    
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Nobody can help me? Is there a way that doesn't involve the calibration of the sensors?

Answer (score 1):

Since every sensor have different values for the same light level, so what I did is to record the `minimum` and the `maximum` values that will be captured during the application lifetime, and I stored these values as a `Min` and `Max`, after a few days of using the application, all the devices will have almost the same value that I can reliable on.
as the initial state, I considered the min value is `1000` and the max value is `0`. (I stored it in the SharedPreferences).
then I will update these values by considering the current `Lux` value of the sensor.
and then I will calculate the **`percentage`** of the lighting.
this is the code that I wrote:

```
float luxValue = o.getAsFloat("double_light_lux");

//here I update the value in sharedPreferences
updateMaxAndMinValue(context, luxValue);

float percentageValue = scale(LightMetadata.getMinValue(context),
                LightMetadata.getMaxValue(context),
                0,
                100,
                luxValue);
```

the updating function:

```
public static void updateMaxAndMinValue(Context context, float luxValue) {
    float currentMax = LightMetadata.getMaxValue(context); //0 as init.
    float currentMin = LightMetadata.getMinValue(context); //1000 as init.

    if (luxValue > currentMax)
        LightMetadata.setMaxValue(context, luxValue);
    if (luxValue < currentMin)
        LightMetadata.setMinValue(context, luxValue);
}
```

and I calculate the percentage by scaling the value from min -> max to 0 -> 100
this is the function:

```
/**
 * @param min   old min value
 * @param max   old max value
 * @param a     new min value
 * @param b     new max value
 * @param value the value that want to scale
 * @return new scaled value
 */
public static float scale(float min, float max, float a, float b, float value) {

    //       (b-a)(x - min)
    //f(x) = --------------  + a
    //          max - min

    float scaled;
    float numerator = (b - a) * (value - min);
    float denominator = max - min;

    scaled = (numerator / denominator) + a;
    return scaled;
}
```